# Post a form with jQuery and add it to the page

Tags: jquery, forms, post

Hey!
I have this code for the form:

```
<form class="myform" name="myform" method="POST" action="post.php">
<textarea id="mytextarea" name="mytextarea"></textarea>
<button>Share</button>
</form>
```

I also have this code for the page:

```
<div class="content">
<div class="message">That message</div>
<div class="info">Published 10/10/10 </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="message">That other message</div>
<div class="info">Published 10/9/10 </div>
</div>
```

It's possible to send the form with jQuery, instead of having to reload the whole page? Can I retrive the response of the form and put the response in the top of the first `<div class="content">`?
**Note: I have multiple forms with the same class.**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sending forms with jQuery is fairly easy.

There's a simple function to post data with AJAX, and it's easy to tie in the values of a form:

```
$.post(url, $('#myform').serialize(), function(data) { 
    $('#content').prepend(data);
})
```

`$.post` is the simple way. If you need to check for errors and whatnot, you should check out $.ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax).

Answer (score 0):

To submit a form using jQuery I believe you need to check this out: http://api.jquery.com/submit/

And I am sure you can retrieve the submitted data with the following:

```
$('[name=mytextarea]').val()`
```

Comment: .val() has issues with some older browsers.  Its best to use .attr('value') for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is certainly possible, using AJAX:

```
$('.myform').submit(function(e){
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').prepend(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('oops, something went wrong');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: If I have various forms with the same class, how I can use only the one that user has click "Send"?

Comment: I've just noticed that your question gave the form a `class` of `myform`, rather than an `id`.  I have updated the answer accordingly.  This action will only occur on the form that the user submits.  The `submit` function means "when one of these forms is submitted, do this instead".

Comment: When I click on the "Send" button, the browser loads the `action` URL instead of sending in the same page. Do you know what's happening?

Comment: Yes, you probably didn't copy the `e.preventDefault()` line from the code above.  This would be because I forgot to include it the first time and had to edit the code to correct this!  Apologies.

Comment: I copied it. Check it http://jsfiddle.net/kBzNC/2/ The browser refreshes to the action URL and that's all.

Comment: I'm not sure what wasn't working, but this seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/HaR87/1/  You need to use `type: 'POST'` rather than `method`, sorry.  You'll need to remove the `data+=` line for your script.

Comment: I couldn't use this script. The browser redirects to the url specified in the `action`. I don't know what's happening.